# XPath- Getting Element from a table having dynamic ID

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate my Test Cases using Selenium for an OBIEE application. Now, I need to read a value from a tabular report generated. The problem is, the ID of the last cell where the total is, keeps on changing. 
For example- Currently the id is: db_saw_9270_6_1610_0. 
After refreshing, the ID becomes something else. The 4 numbers in between (9270) changes. The remaining bit are the same. I'm using the following logic to capture this element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@id, '_6_1610_0')]")).getText();
```

But, it is returning org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:

Please tell me where did I go wrong and what should I do?

Comment: can you try ? driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, '_6_1610_0')]")).getText();

Comment: Can you drop a little of your html code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `starts-with` and `substring` (as a substitute for xpath 2.0 methdod `ends-with`):

```
string xpath = "//*[starts-with(@id, 'db_saw_') and substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 8) = '_6_1610_0']"

driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector .//*[starts-with(@id, 'db_saw_') and 'substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 8) = '_6_1610_0'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[starts-with(@id, 'db_saw_') and 'substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 8) = '_6_1610_0'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: don't use the "." in front of "//" ! have a look at my code, it's not in there!

Comment: Getting the same result. :(

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[starts-with(@id, 'db_saw_') and 'substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 8) = '_6_1610_0'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[starts-with(@id, 'db_saw_') and 'substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 8) = '_6_1610_0'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: ahh sorry there is a quote too much before substring -> updated my answer, pls try it again

Answer (score 0):

You can try below xpath:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'db_saw')]")).getText();
```

Comment: No. Actually, there are a lot of elements starting with 'db_saw'.

Comment: @Abhineet Kumar, Ok..so if you are aware of position of required web element, then in that case you can mention the position number like  //*[starts-with(@id, 'db_saw')][2] , this means you want to access 2nd web element from set of web elements identified with particular xpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.CSSselector("a[id*='_6_1610_0']")).getText();
```

Note: the `a` represents a html element.  If your id is in a  element then you have to replace `a` by table.

[Check this out for more examples with css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)